# Spring EL & JSF

Tags: java, spring, jsf, el

I'm currently experimenting with JSF(especially richfaces) in combination with Spring EL.

Is there a way to validate a Spring EL expression without navigating to the actual page where it's defined? What I mean is that, when I got a typo or syntax error in my expression, it's only found when I actually navigate to the page and I'll receive an exception.

Is there a kind of plugin maybe for eclipse(or another IDE) which is capable of that? This would be awesome :-) I've been googling around, but maybe I didn't gave him the right keywords

Answer (score 0):

I have experience with IntelliJ IDEA which have JSF plugin in Ultimate edition. That plugin checks expression language syntax too.

Comment: okay, this sounds nice. Maybe you also know, wheter it validates, if an bean exists e.g.: #{valueController.message} . I mean does it look if an bean valueController exists

Comment: I'm not sure about that. If valueController is JSF managed, plugin checks it. If controller is Spring managed, it doesn't. You probably have Spring controller, then you can use comment declaration in your views. <!--@elvariable id="messages" type="java.util.Map"--> this line is only type information for syntax check.